# Is there a cut function parameter to control digits only after decimal point?

Tags: r

I have to do a plot with some "rules" for the labels :

- the number of digits after the decimal point must be 2
- no scientific writing

But when using the cut function :

```
x <- runif(100, min=0.00000001, max=10000000000)
cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(x, c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,1))), include.lowest=TRUE, dig.lab = 10)
cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(x, c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,1))), include.lowest=TRUE, dig.lab = 2)
```

I can't apply the two rules together. If I set the dig.lab to 2, I have scientific writing for high numbers, and if I set a high dig.lab to have the full numbers, I get a lot of digits after the decimal point...

Is there a solution ?

EDIT :
Example of plot

```
x1 <- runif(50, min=0, max=1)
x2 <- runif(50, min=1, max=1000)
x <- c(x1,x2)
y <- runif(100, min=1, max=6)

d <- data.frame(x, y)
d$factor <- cut(x, breaks=unique(quantile(x, c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,1))), include.lowest=TRUE)

ggplot(d, aes(y, x, color=factor)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: What are you plotting with, base R `plot`? Can you please update the question with an example of the plot and what is wrong with it? Fixing labels in plots is quite easy, just need to know more about what your plot code looks like

Comment: I edited my post with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  q <- quantile(x, c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,1))
  
  labels = paste(sprintf("%.2f", q)[1:5], sprintf("%.2f", q)[2:6], sep = ", ")
  labels[1] <- paste0("[", labels[1], "]")
  labels[2:5] <- paste0("(", labels[2:5], "]")
  
  cut(x, breaks = q, labels = labels, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

**gplot example**

```
  x1 <- runif(50, min=0, max=1)
  x2 <- runif(50, min=1, max=1000)
  x <- c(x1,x2)
  y <- runif(100, min=1, max=6)
  
  d <- data.frame(x, y)
  
  q <- quantile(x, c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.9,1))
  
  labels = paste(sprintf("%.2f", q)[1:5], sprintf("%.2f", q)[2:6], sep = ", ")
  labels[1] <- paste0("[", labels[1], "]")
  labels[2:5] <- paste0("(", labels[2:5], "]")
  
  
  d$factor <- cut(x, breaks = q, labels = labels, include.lowest=TRUE)
  
  ggplot(d, aes(y, x, color=factor)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]